# Sql Query To Sort Door Access Table

Tags: sql

I Have my Door Access Table Like This

```
------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| EmployeeId | EmployeeName | Location |   AccessTime    | ReaderType |
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| _1341      | A            | L1       | 7/11/2014 10:00 | IN         |
| _1342      | B            | L2       | 7/11/2014 10:58 | IN         |
| _1343      | A            | L3       | 7/11/2014 13:39 | OUT        |
| _1344      | B            | L4       | 7/11/2014 13:58 | OUT        |
| _1365      | A            | L5       | 7/11/2014 14:00 | IN         |
| _1366      | B            | L6       | 7/11/2014 14:58 | IN         |
| _1367      | A            | L7       | 7/11/2014 22:42 | OUT        |
| _1368      | B            | L8       | 7/11/2014 23:58 | OUT        |
| _1369      | A            | L5       | 7/12/2014 14:00 | IN         |
| _1370      | B            | L6       | 7/12/2014 14:58 | IN         |
| _1371      | A            | L7       | 7/12/2014 15:42 | OUT        |
| _1372      | B            | L8       | 7/12/2014 16:58 | OUT        |
| _1373      | A            | L5       | 7/12/2014 18:00 | IN         |
| _1374      | B            | L6       | 7/12/2014 18:58 | IN         |
| _1375      | A            | L7       | 7/12/2014 22:42 | OUT        |
| _1376      | B            | L8       | 7/12/2014 23:58 | OUT        |
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
```

i Want out put As Below

```
------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| EmployeeId | EmployeeName | Location |   AccessTime    | ReaderType |
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| _1341      | A            | L1       | 7/11/2014 10:00 | IN         |
| _1341      | A            | L3       | 7/11/2014 13:39 | OUT        |
| _1341      | A            | L5       | 7/11/2014 14:00 | IN         |
| _1341      | A            | L7       | 7/11/2014 22:42 | OUT        |
| _1342      | B            | L2       | 7/11/2014 10:58 | IN         |
| _1342      | B            | L4       | 7/11/2014 13:58 | OUT        |
| _1342      | B            | L6       | 7/11/2014 14:58 | IN         |
| _1342      | B            | L8       | 7/11/2014 23:58 | OUT        |
| _1341      | A            | L5       | 7/12/2014 14:00 | IN         |
| _1341      | A            | L7       | 7/12/2014 15:42 | OUT        |
| _1341      | A            | L5       | 7/12/2014 18:00 | IN         |
| _1341      | A            | L7       | 7/12/2014 22:42 | OUT        |
| _1342      | B            | L6       | 7/12/2014 14:58 | IN         |
| _1342      | B            | L8       | 7/12/2014 16:58 | OUT        |
| _1342      | B            | L6       | 7/12/2014 18:58 | IN         |
| _1342      | B            | L8       | 7/12/2014 23:58 | OUT        |      
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
```

i want find out the details as mentioned above i.e. to find out IN and Out done by each employee on a day.

Table Parameters

```
EmployeeID varchar(20)
EMployeeName varchar(20)
Location varchar(20)
AcessTime DateTime
ReaderType varchar(20)
```

Kindly Help As Soon as Possible.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `DateTime` looks like SQL Server?

Comment: Please try using an [`order by`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php) clause in your `select` statement.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in the output table's ordering, because right now it's unclear what the goal is and there's more than one possible rationale for it.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 Database.
In !st Picture the employee id column written wrong. Actually it should be like picture 2.
I want to display..every transactions of particular employee in order with time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just order by name/id and accessTimeStamp?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the trick is to sort by date first (no time), then employee, then time.

```
select EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Location, AccessTime, ReaderType
from DoorAccessTable
order by cast(AccessTime AS DATE), EmployeeID, AccessTime
```